# Java email content is empty

Tags: java, email

I have snippet of codes where I send out email with excel file attachment. All works fine where I can see title and even the file attachment. The only thing does not appear is the email content. I have tested that my emailContent variable is not empty. What else can I do to make it appear ? I have even enabled this line of codes messageBodyPart.setText(emailContent); yet the same.
But if enabled this part multipart1.addBodyPart(emailContent); I get error

```
 error: no suitable method found for addBodyPart(String)
                                multipart1.addBodyPart(emailContent);

try 
{

    Message emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);            
    emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(origin1));
    emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(receiptnt1));
    emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(receiptnt2));
    emailMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,InternetAddress.parse(cc1));
    emailMessage.setSubject(emailTitle);
    emailMessage.setText(emailContent);

    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

     // Fill the message
     //messageBodyPart.setText(emailContent);*/

     Multipart multipart1 = new MimeMultipart();
     // Part two is attachment
     messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
     messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
     messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
     multipart1.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     // Put parts in message
     emailMessage.setContent(multipart1);
    //System.out.println("\n\nSend email :"+eMArray[0]);

     transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());


}
catch (Exception e) 
{
System.out.println("Transport Problem");
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have initialized

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
```

Two times. And before the second initialization you're adding the body contents.
So remove the line

```
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPary();
```

Line and it will work fine.

Use the following code.

```
Message emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(origin1));
        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receiptnt1));
        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receiptnt2));
        emailMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc1));
        emailMessage.setSubject(emailTitle);
//            emailMessage.setText(emailContent);

        Multipart multipart1 = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        // Fill the message
        messageBodyPart.setText(emailContent);
        // Part two is attachment
        BodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        attachment.setFileName(filename);
        multipart1.addBodyPart(attachment);
        multipart1.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // Put parts in message
        emailMessage.setContent(multipart1);
        //System.out.println("\n\nSend email :"+eMArray[0]);
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
```

Comment: Ok I have remove the second line but I have this error here  multipart1.addBodyPart(emailContent); as " error: no suitable method found for addBodyPart(String)
                                multipart1.addBodyPart(emailContent);"

Comment: So this " emailMessage.setText(emailContent);" does not do anything right? I have removed it. I would like to understand further why do we have 2 body part because the file is support to be multi part right? I am bit lost here.

Comment: Another problem I notice now is that my content is also attached as another .txt file

Comment: In gmail the content appear twice but in other in outlook it comes as attachment.

Comment: I just want to understand further why do we have two body part. i know one is you set as the content and the other is the file? How does it know the difference one is the attachment?

Comment: i also dont know exactly why to use two body parts...bt you can see this [link](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-with-attachment-in-java)